# What regex expression will match all characters except ", except when it is \"?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to parse an apache log, and I'm having problems with the right syntax for the referer because it is a string inside `"` (double-quotes), that can also have `\"` inside it.

`"([^"]*)"`  doesn't work when there is a `\"` in the string.

How do I start at the 1st double-quote, then take all characters that are not double-quotes, unless it's `\"`, in which case I include it, and keep going?

Comment: Which regex engine are you using?

Comment: wait ! i just checked in `python3`'s `re` module. `"([^"]*)"` seems to work fine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If any of these answers have solved your issue, please accept the one which you feel best addressed the problem you're facing. This is for the benefit others who might have the same issue in the future, as well as to allow others on this site to know that your issue has been resolved. Also, once you've obtained enough reputation (15 or more) please upvote any answer which helped you or which you feel was exceptionally well written even if it wasn't the solution you ended up using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this:

```
"((?:[^"]|\\")*)"
```

It will match zero or more of any character other than a double-quote or a slash-double-quote pair, all surrounded by double-quotes.

Comment: This will cause problems, though, if there can be other escape sequences in the string, for example if the string ends in two backslashes.

Comment: @TimPietzcker That's a good point. I'm not sure that's needed, but it's worth considering.

Comment: Most regexp engines prefer to match earlier alternatives to later ones, even if a later alternative results in a longer overall match. So the sequence of alternatives may need to be switched to `\\"|[^"]` or the character class changed to `[^"\\]` to prevent a match from stopping at the first `"`.

Answer (score 1):

Could there be other escapes in the string, for example `"hello \\"`? In that case, you need a more general approach:

```
"((?:\\.|[^"\\])*)"
```

Comment: +1 but I assume the capture group is there for a reason. I'd recommend wrapping everything inside the quotes with a `(`…`)`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? A negative-lookbehind to exclude a `\` before the closing `"`

```
"(.+?)(?<!\\)"
```

Answer (score 0):

This will match two quotes with any number of escaped quotes in-between:

```
"\([^"]\|\\"\)*"
```

First it looks for a quote.  Next it searches for zero to infinity of the following:

- a non-quote character
- a quote character preceded by a backslash

Comment: @p.s.w.g: Not for a POSIX BRE, which *might* be what the OP is using to parse his Apache logs.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Fair enough. Without further clarification from OP it's hard to know what the correct pattern should be.

Comment: Sure does depend on what regex standard you are using.  I tested on sed.